# Pusher/Chatkit: InstanceID in the path and access token don't match

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, websocket, chatkit

#### What?

I am currently building a react native app with chatkit, however the authentication seems to fail and keeps bringing back the following message: `Instance ID in the path and the access token don't match`

I'm using Laravel as a backend and have the following route:
`Route::post('/chatkit-auth-user', 'API\MessagesController@authenticateChatkitUser');`

Within this method I authenticate the user depending on their user ID like so:

```
public function authenticateChatkitUser(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->input('user_id');
    $authData = $this->chatkit->authenticate([
        'user_id' => "{$userId}",
    ]);

    return response()
        ->json(
            $authData['body'],
            $authData['status']
        );
}
```

The token is generate which is then obviously passed into the TokenProvider instance like so:

```
const url = 'https://my-endpoint.com/api/chatkit-auth-user';
const userToken = this.state.user.authToken;
const tokenProvider = new Chatkit.TokenProvider({
  url,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + userToken,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});
const chatManager = new Chatkit.ChatManager({
  instanceLocator: '<MY_INSTANCE_LOCATOR_ID>',
  userId: `${this.state.user.userId}`,
  tokenProvider: tokenProvider
});

chatManager.connect().then(currentUser => {
  this.state.currentUser = currentUser;
  console.log(currentUser);
  this.currentUser.subscribeToRoom({
    roomId: CHATKIT_ROOM_ID,
    hooks: {
      onNewMessage: this.onReceive.bind(this)
    }
  });
});
```

`currentUser` never gets consoled and always returns a 403 with the message in the title. From the docs, I think I've implemented everything correctly, I have even span up a heroku app with https://github.com/pusher/chatkit-server-node, the same issue still occurs.
I have spent a couple of days trying to figure this out and would appreciate if I could get some guidance if I'm doing anything wrong!